# Pay Pal IPN Notification not working in sandbox account

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am using paypal sandbox account, I have buy now button. 
My form is here : index.php

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxxxx@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://xxxx.net/success.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://xxxxx.net/cancel.php">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://xxx.net/ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Bike">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.99">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="ADDEdEd3dd3">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Here is my success.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("host","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("db");
if($con == null) {
        echo "Not any connection..";
} else {
        $re = mysql_query("insert into test(value) values('inserted')");
        if($re != 0) {
             echo "Data inserted..";
        } else {
             echo "Error while adding data..";
        }
}
?>
```

I have enable IPN notificatin setting and url, also i have enabled auto redirect url, all the things working fine. but IPN notification is not working.

Any idea, i am just trying to ping this page.

Answer (score 1):

Try the IPN Simulator here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator and see if it can send the IPN message or not. IF it fails - it would show you the reason.